# What does this mean in python?

Tags: python

I am having difficulty in understand some code in python and would really appreciate any help on it.

```
condition = "{field}::{cast} {operator} {value}".format(**{
    'field': field_exp(field),
    'cast': cast,
    'value': json.dumps(parameter).replace('"', "'"),
    'operator': operator})
```

I cannot understand what's really happening in this statement. what does the "double colon" do? And what does format(**... mean?

Further in the code there is another line:

```
condition = "jsonb_typeof({field}::jsonb) is {not} null".format(**{
    'field': field_exp(field),
    'not': 'not' if parameter else ''})
```

This statement again follows similar pattern. I will really appreciate if someone could explain what's going on here.

Thank you,
Asanas

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: The double colon doesn't do anything special. It just means the resulting string will have two colons in it, the same way your second string will have "jsonb_typeof" and "is" and "null" in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double colon doesn't do anything.  It's just a fixed part of the format string.

The `**` notation allows keyword arguments to be specified from a `dict`.  Here's a simple, similar example that should make this clear.  I assigned the `dict` to a variable rather than using it in-line to make it more obvious what's happening:

```
>>> vals = {"a":"w", "b":"x", "c":"y", "d":"z"}
>>> "{a}::{b} {c} {d}".format(**vals)
'w::x y z'
>>>
```

As you can see, `format` is just substituting the values from its keyword arguments, which are given by `vals`.

Comment: thank you so much. I got it!